# Stopwatch template

Tags: c++, c++11, template, timer

It's often useful to be able to time code, for instance, to evaluate alternative approaches to the same problem.  Because this is a thing I use frequently, I have created this Stopwatch templated class that I'd like for you all to review. Unlike some [other recent code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2398/homemade-stopwatch-class), this class is intended to be cross-platform and relies only on a working implementation of the `std::chrono` utilities in C++11.

Specifically, does the interface make sense?  Could the code be improved?  Also, I have thought it might be nice to provide some kind of a "units" function to return, say, a `std::string` containing "ms" if `TimeT` is set to `std::chrono::milliseconds` but ultimately decided against complicating the interface.  I'd be open to comments on that decision as well.

### stopwatch.h

```
#ifndef STOPWATCH_H
#define STOPWATCH_H
#include <chrono>

template<typename TimeT = std::chrono::microseconds, 
    typename ClockT=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
    typename DurationT=double>
class Stopwatch
{
private:
    std::chrono::time_point<ClockT> _start, _end;
public:
    Stopwatch();
    void start();
    DurationT restart();
    DurationT stop();
    DurationT elapsed() const;
};

template<typename TimeT, typename ClockT, typename DurationT>
Stopwatch<TimeT, ClockT, DurationT>::Stopwatch() 
{ 
    start(); 
}

template<typename TimeT, typename ClockT, typename DurationT>
void Stopwatch<TimeT, ClockT, DurationT>::start() 
{ 
    _start = _end = ClockT::now(); 
}

template<typename TimeT, typename ClockT, typename DurationT>
DurationT Stopwatch<TimeT, ClockT, DurationT>::stop() 
{ 
    _end = ClockT::now(); 
    return elapsed(); 
}

template<typename TimeT, typename ClockT, typename DurationT>
DurationT Stopwatch<TimeT, ClockT, DurationT>::restart()
{ 
    DurationT ret = stop();
    start();
    return ret;
}

template<typename TimeT, typename ClockT, typename DurationT>
DurationT Stopwatch<TimeT, ClockT, DurationT>::elapsed() const
{ 
    auto delta = std::chrono::duration_cast<TimeT>(_end-_start); 
    return delta.count(); 
}
#endif
```

### stoptest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "stopwatch.h"

int main()
{
    const int iterations = 1000000;
    double sqrtsum = 0;
    Stopwatch<> sw;
    for (int i=0; i<iterations; ++i)
        sqrtsum += sqrt(i);
    std::cout << "calculated " << sqrtsum << " in " << sw.restart() << " us\n";
    sqrtsum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<iterations; ++i)
        sqrtsum += pow(i,0.5);
    std::cout << "calculated " << sqrtsum << " in " << sw.stop() << " us\n";
}
```

### A few words about usage

The goal was to create a minimal but complete interface.  The constructor does nothing except calling `start`.

`start` sets both starting and ending times to the current underlying clock's `now()` and essentially functions as a *reset* (which was another name I considered for this function.)

`elapsed` does not modify the underlying `Stopwatch` and only returns the difference between the internally stored `_end` and `_start`.

`stop` returns the elapsed time between "now" and the internally stored `_start` and so can be used to measure several times all relative to the same start time.

`restart` does the same thing as `stop` except it also resets the start time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Ergonomy

The `restart` method seems a bit unnatural: I wouldn't guess it returns the elapsed duration. When you look at this command as a sentence, it doesn't look right:

> ```
> std::cout << "calculated " << sqrtsum << " in " << sw.restart() << " us\n";
> ```

How about renaming to `delta()` ?

Actually, I have a similar thing in Java. I have a `delta()` method that returns the elapsed time since the last call (or since start), and an `elapsed()` method that returns the total time since start. My `start()`, `stop()`, `restart()` methods don't return anything, and I feel it's right that way. Perhaps you can consider this alternative approach.

#### Coding style

I don't know what is the standard coding style in C++ world (and would appreciate a link!), but I think many of the standards I know in Java could be applied to C++ too, so I'll mention a few.

> ```
> for (int i=0; i<iterations; ++i)
> sqrtsum += pow(i,0.5);
> ```

It's recommended to use braces and indenting the block even for single statement fors, ifs, to avoid mistakes. Also, spaces around operators make the code more readable, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
{
    sqrtsum += pow(i, 0.5);
}
```

(Btw I'm very happy to see you using `++i` instead of `i++`, few people I know appreciate its significance!)

#### Modeling real life

I'm getting the feeling that the `start` and `stop` methods come from the notion of a stop watch in real life. In real life you first click start, then click stop, and read the elapsed time. To measure another thing, you click reset and then start again, and so on.

I think you can free yourself from a real life stop watch and think in terms of the functionality you're actually going to use:

- Create `stopwatch`
- Do something
- Print elapsed time
- Do something else
- Print elapsed time
- ...

The `stop` and `restart` actions just don't come into play here. When you think of what you actually want to do, the terms just don't pop up like that. You just want the elapsed time since the last "tick", again and again. `start` also isn't there, because it make sense to do that when you create the `stopwatch`, simply because there's nothing else really to do in the constructor of this object. Instead of doing nothing, you might as well just start it.

So I would rename `restart` to `delta` or similar (`elapsed`, or even `tick`), and omit `start` and `stop` completely. "stopwatch" might not be the best name for the class either. (I called mine "timer", but not sure that's much better.)

Comment: C++ does not have a "standard coding style". `++i` vs `i++` is basically a micro-optimisation because the compiler will typically (well, always really) do it for you in loops. Outside of that this advice is good.

Comment: I thought about naming and what (if anything) to return. Note that `stop`, `start` and `restart` all imply a command, while `elapsed` is merely reporting, accurately reflecting actual implementation.  That's the philosophy behind the existing names, but I'm open to suggestions for a better replacement set of names. Return values were based on observation of how I actually used the stopwatch.

Comment: That's the thing, since they imply a command, they don't fit intuitively in sentences like `"calculated x in " << restart() << " seconds"` or `"calculated x in " << stop() << " seconds"`. Something that sounds reporting or evoking the notion of elapsed time would be more natural, and read like a sentence.

Comment: @janos: In principle, I agree.  I just couldn't think of anything better.  Can you?

Comment: I name it `delta` (as I already wrote it in the answer). A sentence like `"calculated x in " << sw.delta() << " seconds"` seems natural to me. Other ideas for the name: `elapsed`, `tick`. And I don't have `start`, `stop`, `restart` methods, as all I ever use is the `.delta()`.

Comment: @janos: your usage example is pretty close but not quite complete.  Consider code chunks A,B,C,D,E which run in that order.  I want to use a single stopwatch to measure and store (in an external vector) the durations of A, A+B, C, and E (I don't care about the duration of D).  Not sure how I'd do that with neither `stop` nor `restart`.

Comment: `A = sw.delta()`, `A + B = A + sw.delta()`, `C = sw.delta()`, throw away `sw.delta()`, `E = sw.delta()`.

Comment: @janos "In real life you first click start, then click stop, and read the elapsed time" Sometimes I read the elapsed time before I press stop if the process I am timing is ongoing i.e. in a multi-lap race.

Answer (score 8):

I would like this interface:

```
StopWatch    sw;

SomeTimeType   time = sw.time([](){
    for (int i=0; i<iterations; ++i)
         sqrtsum += sqrt(i);
});

std::cout << "It took: " << time << " Units\n";
```

I don't like the interface as it stands because you can call the functions in any order (which makes no sense). The interface should be designed so you can not call the functions in the wrong order. Which points at a design that does not involve explicit functions calls but a more declarative approach.

```
DurationT restart();        // Probably need to check the documentation on what that means.

DurationT elapsed() const;  // What happens if I call this on a currently running watch?
                            // I would still expect it to give me the current elapsed time
                            // but currently it return 0
```

Comment: Perhaps the interface is too flexible, but being able to accumulate time spent in multiple arbitrary slices of code is a useful feature. Also, I'd prefer to measure performance without affecting variable scopes, which lambda could do.

Comment: @200_success: One doesn't have to choose, really. I have a templated function called `timeit` that uses the `Stopwatch` class and accepts a function (including a lambda).  I didn't post it because I found I never actually use it.

Comment: @200_success: Multiple arbitrary slices are not really affected (because addition is not hard to do).

Comment: @LokiAstari +1 "What happens if I call this on a currently running watch? I would still expect it to give me the current elapsed time but currently it returns 0" I also made this point, it's pretty serious.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe we all have different ideas on what a `Stopwatch` is. I see a `Stopwatch` as an object that measures the `total_elapsed_time` when the `Stopwatch` is **active**.  That means functionally, a `Stopwatch` should have:

1. `start()` - If inactive, define the start time for this period and make the `Stopwatch` active.
2. `stop()` - If active, add the elapsed time during this duration period to the total elapsed time the `Stopwatch` was active, then set the `Stopwatch` as inactive.  Whether it returns the elapsed time is up to you.
3. `split()` or `elapsed()` - If inactive, return the `total_elapsed_time` the `Stopwatch` was active for.  If active, calculate/update the `total_elapsed_time` the `Stopwatch` was active for and return it.
4. `reset(state)` - The `total_elapsed_time` of the `Stopwatch` is reset to `0`.  State of the `Stopwatch` could be active or inactive (similar to the CTor).

An example of a Stopwatch class that follows this pattern of states used in production code is the [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the .Net standard library.

I'm not a big fan of returning `double`s for your `DurationT`s.  Return your durations as `TypeT` objects to preserve the `std::chrono` type-safe property.

> Also, I have thought it might be nice to provide some kind of a "units" function to return, say, a `std::string` containing "ms" if `TimeT` is set to `std::chrono::milliseconds` but ultimately decided against complicating the interface. I'd be open to comments on that decision as well.

A conversion operator  (`operator std::string()`) that wraps `elapsed()` might work.  Use `TimeT::period::num` and `TimeT::period::den` against a [prefix look-up table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) (could just use the `std::ratio` as your key).

Comment: I like your prefix look-up table idea.  I am experimenting with implementations of it now.

Comment: I'd say the units thing should be delegated to a different class i.e. a `TimeFormatter` class. You could then provide different formatters for different time units and they'd all work through the same class/interface. +1 for Laying out the way a stopwatch should work, I totally agree that a stopwatch should work like that and the stopwatch presented does not.

Comment: @Pharap Your idea is much better than mine.

Answer (score 5):

I have several things I'd like to mention, but to name a few:

- Your stopwatch doesn't truly stop. What good is a stopwatch that doesn't
  stop?
- `start`'s body should be separated into two lines. Doing multiple
  assignments on a single line is bound to confuse at least one reader.
- `Stop` and `Restart` should return either void or a bool indicating
  success.
- `elapsed` should return a valid result even if the `stopwatch` is
  running, you should not have to stop the `stopwatch` just to be able to get an accurate reading. Think of a real stopwatch, you don't need to stop it to read how much time has elapsed, you get an updated value when you consciously check for one.
- The `stopwatch` should have a way of telling what state it is in to
  prevent calls being made out of order by throwing exceptions or by
  ignoring calls being made out of order by only changing state when it
  is valid to do so (i.e. stop would only run its body if the
  `stopwatch` were in the running state).

Comment: The stopwatch **does** stop. But just like a mechanical stopwatch, it doesn't stop time itself (represented here by the underlying `ClockT`).

Comment: @Edward If I were to call `stop`, then record the result of `elapsed`, then call stop again, it would change the value of `elapsed` such that it would be as if the stopwatch had still been running. To truly make your stopwatch stop you should have a way of maintaining state, be it a `bool` indicating whether the stopwatch is running or an `enum` with values of `Running` and `Stopped`.

Comment: Have you got a use case in mind in which you'd use that?

Comment: Calculating load times of reading multiple files, but pausing during the processing of the data, or vice-versa, or any other situation where you need to pause the stopwatch.

Comment: Sounds like `pause()` and `unpause()` make more sense...  You could store the paused time and when unpausing just add the difference to the start time or keep track of a paused time total to subtract when calling `elapsed()`.  I could see a `lap()` call being useful too, say if you wanted to use one stopwatch to record several parts of loading a file (i.e. reading from disk, parsing, inserting into database, etc.) with a lap() for each and the total time for processing the file from start to finish at the end.

Comment: For recording of individual pieces and also the whole, when I've wanted to do that I typically either store the values in a vector and add them or keep a running accumulator external to the class.

Answer (score 3):

Every time I've needed a stopwatch, this is the sort of thing I've been after. No complications, just a simple start and stop function. I reckon you just document what the units are in, and people can do conversion themselves.

One thing that is convenient is something I saw in the .NET version of this, where you just have a static class that returns a running clock. Makes it even easier.

```
var stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

// Do something

stopwatch.Stop();
```

Actually it looks like you're already doing that.

Comment: Note that the reason `StartNew` is a static method is because it is separate from the constructor, which avoids starting the `Stopwatch`. +1 for looking at an existing implementation as a reference though.