# Count number of occurences of a digit in the range

Tags: c++

Left limit, right limit and the digit to be counted is entered. This code works only for whole numbers i. e. from 0 to n. This code returns the number of occurence of the digit `n` in the given range. Please review this code and suggest improvements.

```
#include <iostream>

int count_n(int l, int r, int n)
{
    if (r <= l)
    {
        std::cerr << "Right limit must greater then left limit\n";
        return 0;
    }

    if (l < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Only positive integers\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = l; i <= r; ++i)
    {
        int i_copy = i;
        while (i_copy != 0)
        {
            if (i_copy % 10  == n)
            {
                count++;
            }
            i_copy = i_copy / 10;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int left_limit, right_limit, num;
    std::cout << "Enter left limit, right limit and the number(Only positive numbers)\n";
    std::cin >> left_limit >> right_limit >> num;

    int result = count_n(left_limit, right_limit, num);
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Enter left limit, right limit and the number(Only for positive numbers)
1 20 0
2
```

Comment: There is a much better algorithm.  See [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117670/finding-the-sum-of-all-the-segment-counts-of-a-7-segment-display-in-a-range/117693#117693) for some hints as to how to derive it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/231373/136864), you should specify validation for `n` ( `digit` ).
Also, it may be better to group validations into separate function.

```
void check_input(int min_left, int max_right, int digit) {
  if (max_right <= min_left)
    throw std::invalid_argument("right is <= left, expected right > left");
  if (min_left < 0)
    throw std::invalid_argument("left < 0, expected left > 0");
  if (digit <= 0)
    throw std::invalid_argument("digit <= 0");
    //throw std::invalid_argument("number <= 0");  
  if (digit > 9)
    throw std::invalid_argument("digit > 9");

  ////number:
  //if (digit > max_right)
  //  throw std::invalid_argument("number > right limit");
}

int count_digit_entries(int min_left, int max_right, int digit) {
//...
}

int main() {
  int left_limit, right_limit, num;
  std::cout << "Enter left limit, right limit and the number(Only positive numbers)\n";
  std::cin >> left_limit >> right_limit >> num;

  check_input(left_limit, right_limit, num);

  int result = count_digit_entries(left_limit, right_limit, num);

  std::cout << "\nTotal: " << result << "\n";
}
```

You may want to find not only digits but a whole numbers.

```
//...


#define DEBUG
#ifdef  DEBUG
#define debug(x) x
#else 
#define debug(x)
#endif


int count_digit_entries(int min_left, int max_right, int search_number) {
  int count = 0;

  int mod = 10;
  while(search_number / mod > 0) mod = mod * 10; // 279 -> 1000

  for (int current_number = min_left, right = max_right; current_number < right; ++current_number) {
    int copied_current_number = current_number; // 542793

    while (copied_current_number >= search_number) {
        // 542793 - 279 % 1000    >0 
        // 54279 - 279 % 1000     =0

      if ( ( (copied_current_number - search_number) % mod ) == 0 ) { 
        debug(std::cout << current_number << " ");
        ++count;
      };
      copied_current_number = copied_current_number / 10; 
      // 542793 -> 54279

    };
  };

  return count;
};
```

Output:

```
Enter left limit, right limit and the number(Only positive numbers)
0 1000 25
25 125 225 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 325 425 525 625 725 825 925 
Total: 20
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Error handling

Since `0` could also be a valid result for the input (e.g. `6 10 5`), I'd prefer to indicate invalid input via exceptions rather than the return value:

```
int count_n(int l, int r, int n) {
    if (r <= l) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Right limit must greater then left limit");
    }

    if (l < 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Only positive integers");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Thus the caller of the function can distinguish invalid input parameters from valid results by putting the call of `count_n()` into a `try / catch` block.

#### 2. Function and parameter naming

Naming the function `count_n()` and the parameter for the digit to count `n` is a bit unclear.
You should rather use the signature

```
 int count_digit(int min_left, int max_right, int digit);
```

to make the intend of that function clearer.