# Solve a set of "restricted" linear equations efficiently

Tags: c++, algorithm, object-oriented, c++11, interview-questions

I was recently asked to solve the following challenge (in C++) as part of the interview process. However, I haven't heard from them at all afterwards, and based on past experiences of unsuccessful applicants that I've read online, my submission didn't meet their standards. Since I did solve the challenge to the best of my abilities, I'm at a loss to understand in what ways I could have made a better solution. I'm posting the problem statement (in my own words) and my solution here. Please critique it as you would for a potential applicant to your team (as a means for gauging whether it's worthwhile to have a subsequent phone-screen with such an applicant).

> ### Input Details
>
> The utility would take as input an input file containing a list of
>   equations, one per line. Each equation has the following format: 
>   `<LHS> = <RHS>`, where `LHS` is the left-hand side of the equation and is always a variable name.
>   `RHS` is the right hand side of the equation and can be composed of the following only:
>
> - Variables
> - Unsigned integers
> - The `+` operator
>
> #### Assumptions
>
> Input is well-formed i.e.
>
> - Number of variables = Number of equations, with each variable occurring on the   LHS of exactly one equation.
> - The system of equations has an unique solution, and does not have circular   dependencies.
> - There are one or more white spaces between each token (numbers, + operator,   variables).
> - A variable name can only be composed of letters from the alphabet (e.g. for which `isalpha(c)` is true).
> - All integers will fit in a C `unsigned long`.
>
> ### Output Format
>
> The utility would print the value of each variable after evaluating the set of equations, in the format `<variable name> = <unsigned integer value>`. The variables would be sorted in ascending (lexicographic) order.
>
> #### Sample Input Output
>
> Input file:
>
> ```
> off = 4 + r + 1
> l   = 1 + or + off
> or  = 3 + 5
> r   = 2
> ```
>
> Expected output for the above input:
>
> ```
> l   = 16
> off = 7
> or  = 8
> r   = 2
> ```

### Implementation Notes

Due to the simplified nature of the input equations, a full-blown linear
equation solver is not required in my opinion (as such a solver would have at least quadratic complexity). A much simplified (and asymptotically faster) solution can be arrived at by modeling the set of input equations as a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG), by observing the dependencies of the variables from the input equations. Once we can model the system as a DAG, the steps to derive the variable values are as follows:

- Construct the dependency DAG, where each node in the graph corresponds to a variable, and \$(a, b)\$ is a directed edge from \$a\$ to \$b\$ *if and only if*  the variable \$a\$ needs to be *fully evaluated* before evaluating \$b\$.
- Order the vertices in the DAG thus constructed using *topological sort*.
- For each vertex in the sorted order, evaluate its corresponding variable fully before moving on to the next vertex.

The algorithm above has a linear complexity, which is the best we could achieve under the current assumptions. I've encapsulated the algorithm in the following class (I've used [Google's C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html) in my code - not sure it's the *best* choice, but I preferred to follow a style guide that's at least recognized by and arrived at by a non-trivial number of engineers.)

Class header file:

```
//
// Class that encapsulates a (constrained) linear equation solver. See README.md
// for assumptions on input restrictions.
//
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

#ifndef _EVALUATOR
#define _EVALUATOR

class Evaluator
{
  private:
    // Stores the values of each variable throughout algorithm
    std::vector<UL>                      variable_values_;

    // Hash tables that store the correspondence between variable name and index
    std::unordered_map<std::string, UL>  variable_index_map_;
    std::unordered_map<UL, std::string>  index_variable_map_;

    // Adjacency list for DAG that stores the dependency information amongst
    // variables. If A[i, j] is an edge, it implies variable 'i' appears on the 
    // RHS of definition of variable 'j'.
    std::vector<std::list<UL> >          dependency_adj_list_;

    // List of equations stored as indices. If the list corresponding to eq[i]
    // contains 'j', then variable 'j' appears on the RHS of variable 'i'.
    std::vector<std::list<UL> >          equation_list_;

    // For efficiency, this list stores the number of dependencies for each
    // variable, which is useful while executing a topological sort.
    std::vector<UL>                      num_dependencies_;

    // Resets all internal data structures
    void  Clear();  

    // Prints values of internal data structures to aid in debugging
    void  PrintState();

    // Adds an entry corresponding to each new variable detected while parsing input
    UL    AddNewVar(std::string& );

    // Parse the input equations from filename given as argument, and build the
    // internal data structures coressponsing to the input.
    bool  ParseEquationsFromFile(const std::string&);

    // If DAG in dependency_adj_list_ has a valid topological order, returns
    // true along with the ordered vertices in the input vector
    bool  GetTopologicalVarOrder(std::vector<UL>&);

  public:
    Evaluator() {};

    /**
     * @brief Evaluate the set of constrained linear equations and returns the
     *        values of the variables as a list.
     *
     * @param[in]  string: Filename containing list of constrained linear equations.
     * @param[in]  vector<string>: If solution exists, returns the values of
     *             variables in lexicographic order (ascending).
     *
     * @return True if solution exists (always exists for valid input), false if
     *              input is not well-formed (See README.md for more details about input
     *              format).
     */
    bool SolveEquationSet(const std::string&, std::vector<std::string>& );
};
#endif
```

The main class file:

```
#include "evaluator.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

#ifdef _EVALUATOR

// Used for early returns if the expression is false 
#define TRUE_OR_RETURN(EXPR, MSG)    \
  do                                 \
  {                                  \
    bool status = (EXPR);            \
    if (status != true)              \
    {                                \
      cerr << __FUNCTION__           \
           << ": " << MSG << endl;   \
      return false;                  \
    }                                \
  } while(0)                 
#endif

using namespace std;
//****  Helper functions local to the file ****

// Returns true if each character in the non-empty string is a digit
bool IsNumber(string s)
{
  return !s.empty() && std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isdigit);
}

// Given a string, returns a vector of tokens separated by whitespace
vector<string> ParseTokensFromString(const string& s)
{
  istringstream   iss(s);
  vector<string>  token_list;
  string          token;
  while (iss >> token)
    token_list.push_back(token);
  return token_list;
}

// Returns true if the string can be a valid variable name (i.e has
// only alphabetical characters in it).
bool IsValidVar(string& v) 
{
  for (auto& c: v)
    TRUE_OR_RETURN(isalpha(c), "Non-alphabetical char in variable: " + v);
  return true;
}

//********************************************

void Evaluator::Clear()
{
  variable_values_.clear();
  variable_index_map_.clear();
  index_variable_map_.clear();
  dependency_adj_list_.clear();
  equation_list_.clear();
  num_dependencies_.clear();
}

void Evaluator::PrintState()
{
  for (auto i = 0U; i < dependency_adj_list_.size(); ++i)
    cout << index_variable_map_[i] << "(" << i << ") =>"  
         << "Value(" << variable_values_[i] << "), Deps(" 
         << num_dependencies_[i] << ")" << endl;
}

// Ensures all data structures correctly set aside an entry for the new variable
UL Evaluator::AddNewVar(string& v)
{
  if (variable_index_map_.count(v) == 0)
  {
    dependency_adj_list_.push_back(list<UL>());
    equation_list_.push_back(list<UL>());
    variable_values_.push_back(0);
    num_dependencies_.push_back(0);
    variable_index_map_.insert(make_pair(v, dependency_adj_list_.size() - 1));
    index_variable_map_.insert(make_pair(dependency_adj_list_.size() - 1, v));

    assert(num_dependencies_.size() == variable_values_.size() &&
           variable_index_map_.size() == variable_values_.size() && 
           variable_values_.size() == dependency_adj_list_.size());
  }
  return variable_index_map_[v];
}

// Parses equation from given input file line-by-line, checking 
// for validity of input at each step and returning true only if 
// all equations were successfully parsed.
bool Evaluator::ParseEquationsFromFile(const string& sEqnFile)
{
  string    line;
  ifstream  infile(sEqnFile);

  // This LUT serves as a sanity check for duplicate definitions of vars
  // As per spec, only ONE definition (appearance as LHS) per variable is handled
  unordered_set<string>  defined_vars; 
  while (getline(infile, line))
  {
    vector<string> tokens = ParseTokensFromString(line);
    string         lhs    = tokens[0];

    // Check if equation is adhering to spec
    TRUE_OR_RETURN(tokens.size() >= 3 && IsValidVar(lhs) && tokens[1] == "=", 
        "Invalid equation: " + line);

    // Check if variable on LHS was previously defined - this would make the 
    // current approach untenable, and require general equation solver.
    TRUE_OR_RETURN(defined_vars.count(lhs) == 0, "Multiple defn for: " + lhs);
    defined_vars.insert(lhs);
    const UL lhs_idx = AddNewVar(lhs);

    // The operands appear in alternate positions in RHS, tracked by isOp
    for (size_t i = 2, isOp = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i, isOp ^= 1)
    {
      string token = tokens[i];
      if (isOp) 
        TRUE_OR_RETURN(token == "+", "Unsupported operator: " + token);
      else 
      {
        if (IsNumber(token))
          variable_values_[lhs_idx] += stol(token);
        else
        {
          TRUE_OR_RETURN(IsValidVar(token), "Invalid variable name: " + token);

          // Token variable must be evaluated before LHS. 
          // Hence adding token => LHS edge, and adding token to RHS of 
          // equation_list_[lhs]
          auto token_idx = AddNewVar(token);
          dependency_adj_list_[token_idx].push_back(lhs_idx);        
          assert(lhs_idx < equation_list_.size());
          equation_list_[lhs_idx].push_back(token_idx);
          num_dependencies_[lhs_idx]++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return (variable_index_map_.size() == dependency_adj_list_.size() && 
          dependency_adj_list_.size() == variable_values_.size());
}

// Execute the BFS version of topological sorting, using queue
bool Evaluator::GetTopologicalVarOrder(vector<UL>& ordered_vertices)
{
  ordered_vertices.clear();
  queue<UL> q;
  for (auto i = 0U; i < dependency_adj_list_.size(); ++i)
    if (num_dependencies_[i] == 0)
      q.push(i);

  while (!q.empty())
  {
    UL var_idx = q.front();
    ordered_vertices.push_back(var_idx);
    q.pop();
    for (auto& nbr: dependency_adj_list_[var_idx])
    {
      assert(num_dependencies_[nbr] >= 0);
      num_dependencies_[nbr]--;
      if (num_dependencies_[nbr] == 0)
        q.push(nbr);
    }
  }
  return (ordered_vertices.size() == dependency_adj_list_.size());
}

// Solves the constrained set of linear equations in 3 phases:
// 1) Parsing equations and construction of the dependency DAG
// 2) Topological sort on the dependency DAG to get the order of vertices
// 3) Substituting the values of variables according to the sorted order,
//    to get the final values for each variable.
bool Evaluator::SolveEquationSet(const string& eqn_file, vector<string>& solution_list)
{
  Clear();
  vector<UL> order;
  TRUE_OR_RETURN(ParseEquationsFromFile(eqn_file), "Parsing Equations Failed");
  TRUE_OR_RETURN(GetTopologicalVarOrder(order), "Topological Order Not Found");

  // Populate variable values in topological order 
  for (auto& idx: order)
    for (auto& nbr: equation_list_[idx])
      variable_values_[idx] += variable_values_[nbr];

  // Get keys from the LUT sorted in ascending order
  set<pair<string, UL> > sorted_var_idx;
  for (auto& vi_pair: variable_index_map_)
    sorted_var_idx.insert(vi_pair);
  for (auto& vi_pair: sorted_var_idx)
    solution_list.push_back(vi_pair.first + " = " + 
        to_string(variable_values_[vi_pair.second]));

  return true;
}
#endif
```

The usage of the class is as follows:

```
   string          eqn_file, log_file;
   Evaluator       evaluate;
   vector<string>  solution_list;

   // Logic to get input filename from user - skipping it here
   bool bStatus = evaluate.SolveEquationSet(eqn_file, solution_list); 

   for (auto& s: solution_list)
     cout << s << endl;
```

Comment: As this is my first "real" question here, any comments on whether this is a suitable question or not is also applicable - I've read the FAQ and posted working code along with design and problem statement. At the very least, vote for closing the question so that I know its not a suitable query to be made to this site :)

Comment: `using namespace std;` that must have been it ;) Joking. Looking into the code.

Comment: I have some difficulties reading the code. Altough there is plenty comments before the functions, I am missing comments _in_ the functions. Like `GetTopologicalVarOrder`: whats happening inside the code. How will the person reviewing or maintaining your code understand that? And then I lose track of what variable does what. The variable naming is not sufficiently clear.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Is that the only comment you have? I don't think bounties apply to comments, so I'll wait for a fully fleshed out answer...

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not in it for the credit. And I have a full time job, which also requires some attention sometimes ;)

Comment: If I was evaluating this code, I would have failed you for that `TRUE_OR_RETURN` macro. `using namespace std;` would also be a severe red flag that you'd need exceptional code to recover from.

Comment: @JackAidley: Thanks for your feedback. I'm trying to understand your feedback better: 1) The TRUE_OR_RETURN macro wasn't there from the very start - i noticed there were a lot of places where I had to do an early exit depending on the result of intermediate calls. Using this macro (IMO) makes it easier to read than `if (!foo()) { cerr << MSG; return false;` - or would you have objected to that line of logic as well? (I didn't want to create custom exceptions as I've heard that could get points docked off for over-engineering). Is there a guideline you use when to use exceptions, and when not?

Comment: @JackAidley Regarding your second comment - I'm a bit surprised actually, as I included `std` *in the .cpp file, not the header file .h*. No other code needs to inherit the std namespace, as its only confined in the .cpp file. Is that considered bad as well? I'd really like to know your rationale behind it (as to how it can affect code in other classes). Again, just trying to understand the rationale, rather than just following the rule blindly.

Comment: Macros are generally toxic, because they debug poorly and behave in odd ways. There are times they are necessary, but if they're not completely necessary I would avoid their use. As for making it easier to read, your alternative can be understood by anyone familiar with C++, whereas your macro needs to be located and checked with extreme care (because it's a macro and they're deeply unsafe) to understand what it is doing.

Comment: `using namespace std;` dumps the entire namespace into yours, undermining the point of having namespaces in the first place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.  Note that I am not referring to Google's C++ style guide, so contradictions between my suggestions and that guide simply mean that Google is wrong.  :)

### Fix the bugs

There is a spurious `#endif` at the end of `evaluator.cpp` that prevents it from being compiled.  The `evaluator.h` class relies on an undefined type `UL`.  If that's something that's defined by your particular compiler, you should be aware that it's non-standard and therefore not portable.  I fixed this by adding this line:

```
using UL = unsigned long;
```

### Make sure you have all required `#include`s

The `evaluator.cpp` uses `cerr` and `endl` in the `TRUE_OR_RETURN` macro but doesn't `#include <istream>`.  It also uses `ifstream` but doesn't `#include <fstream>`. Also, carefully consider which `#include`s are part of the interface (and belong in the `.h` file) and which are part of the implementation.  For example, the interface relies on `std::string` but the `.h` file is missing `#include <string>`.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Don't use `std::endl` when '\n' will do

Using `std::endl` emits a `\n` and flushes the stream.  Unless you really need the stream flushed, you can improve the performance of the code by simply emitting `'\n'` instead of using the potentially more computationally costly `std::endl`.

### Avoid function-like macros

In modern C++, there are very few places that a function-like macro should be used.  Let's look at yours:

```
// Used for early returns if the expression is false 
#define TRUE_OR_RETURN(EXPR, MSG)    \
  do                                 \
  {                                  \
    bool status = (EXPR);            \
    if (status != true)              \
    {                                \
      cerr << __FUNCTION__           \
           << ": " << MSG << endl;   \
      return false;                  \
    }                                \
  } while(0)
```

There are a number of problems with this macro.  First, we don't really need the `status` variable at all. The `if` could be written: `if (!(EXPR))`.  Second, `cerr` and `endl` (if it's used at all, see previous suggestion) should be fully qualified with the `std` namespace.  Third, `__FUNCTION__`, while common, is not standard.  One could use `__func__` instead, which is standard.  Fourth, I'd much rather see the macro eliminated entirely in favor of simple inline code, not least because printing the internal function name is not very user friendly and is only meaningful to a programmer working on the code.

### Use const references where practical

The code currently declares its `IsNumber` function like so:

```
bool IsNumber(string s)
{
  return !s.empty() && std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isdigit);
}
```

This has two problems.  First it passes by value, so a new string is created on every call.  This is quite wasteful of both time and memory.  Second, it should actually be a const reference, since `s` is not modified within the function.

### Think carefully about signed versus unsigned

If, indeed, my assumption about `UL` meaning `unsigned long` is correct, then this assert is useless:

```
assert(num_dependencies_[nbr] >= 0);
```

Because `num_dependencies_` is defined as:

```
std::vector<UL>                      num_dependencies_;
```

So therefore the `assert` can never be false.

### Declare only one variable per line

The test code includes this line:

```
string          eqn_file, log_file;
```

It's generally better style to declare each variable on its own line.

### Don't visually align variables

The code currently contains a number of lines that look like these:

```
string          eqn_file, log_file;
Evaluator       evaluate;
vector<string>  solution_list;
```

While that may look pretty to some people, and perhaps you use an IDE or other code formatter that does that automatically, in my experience, it simply creates a maintenance headache because another programmer (who perhaps is not using your same tools) who modifies this (e.g. according to these suggestions)  to add the missing namespace specifications ends up with this:

```
std::string          eqn_file; 
std::string log_file;
Evaluator       evaluate;
std::vector<std::string>  solution_list;
```

Now it doesn't look so pretty, so either that poor programmer has to redo all of the fiddly alignment or better, in my view, is to eliminate it entirely to end up with this:

```
std::string eqn_file; 
std::string log_file;
Evaluator evaluate;
std::vector<std::string> solution_list;
```

### Rethink your interfaces

Right now, the code is used like this:

```
bool bStatus = evaluate.SolveEquationSet(eqn_file, solution_list);
```

This has a couple of problems.  First, why doesn't `SolveEquationSet` return a `solution_list` instead of taking it as a parameter (in an overly subtle way, by reference)?  Second, it would be much more flexible if it would take a generic `istream &` rather than a string that's presumed to be a file name.  This would allow, for example, simple testing by constructing equations in a `std::stringstream` and passing a reference to that for evaluation.  Third, why is `evaluate` a class with non-static functions rather than, say a functor?  Once it has returned the solution set, there's not really anything useful to do with it, so I'd suggest that the usage should look more like this:

```
auto solution_list = EquationSolver(infile);
if (solution_list.size() == 0) {
    std::cout << "There are no solutions\n";
} else {
    for (const auto &sol : solution_list) {
        std::cout << sol << '\n';
    }
}
```

### Simplify your algorithm

The solution you've written works, which is good, but it's not very efficient in terms of time or space.  Here's an alternative approach:

1. scan each equation into a `Variable` class which contains the variable name, a `std::set` of dependencies and a single `unsigned` for the sum of any constants
2. process the list by adding the value of each `Variable` with 0 dependencies to the constant of the current `Variable`, eliminating that `Variable` from the dependencies
3. repeat from step 2 until all dependency lists are empty

This is guaranteed to work because of the definition of the input equations and uses only a single nested `std::set` instead  of maps, sets, vectors, and queues as with the current solution.

### Test the code

We were both wondering about the complexity and runtime speed, so I wrote a test harness.  It uses [this stopwatch class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58055/stopwatch-template) for timing.  I made a slight change to your code to allow it to either take its input from a stream or by passing a filename and put that in "orig.h" and factored out the revised version from [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158752/simple-linear-equation-solver) into "Variable.h".

```
#include "orig.h"
#include "Variable.h"
#include "stopwatch.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>

std::string original(std::istream &in) {
    static Evaluator evaluate;
    std::vector<std::string> solution_list;
    evaluate.SolveEquationSet(in, solution_list); 
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (const auto &item: solution_list)
        ss << item << '\n';
    return ss.str();
}

std::string Edward(std::istream &in) {
    auto sol{solve(in)};
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (const auto &item: sol)
        ss << item << '\n';
    return ss.str();
}

class TestRig {
public:
    TestRig(std::string myname,
        std::string (*myfunc)(std::istream &in)) :
        name{myname}, testfunc{myfunc}
    {}
    std::string operator()(const std::string &instring) const {
        std::stringstream in{instring};
        Stopwatch<> sw;
        auto solution = testfunc(in);
        sw.stop();
        std::cout << name << ": " << sw.elapsed() << "us\n";
        return solution;
    }
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string (*testfunc)(std::istream &in);
};

static const TestRig tests[]{
    { "Edward", Edward }, 
    { "original", original }, 
};

int main() {
    const std::string input{"b = c + d + 3\nd = e + 4\na = b + c + d + 1\ne = 7\nc = d + 2"};
    std::stringstream in{input}; 
    const auto golden = original(in);
    for (auto testcount = 10; testcount; --testcount) {
        for (const auto &test: tests) {
            auto sol = test(input);
            assert(sol == golden);
        }
    }
}
```

### Results

I compiled the program on my 64-bit Linux machine with g++ version 6.3.1 and -O2 optimization.  Here's what I got when I ran the program:

```
Edward: 18us
original: 32us
Edward: 12us
original: 18us
Edward: 11us
original: 16us
Edward: 10us
original: 15us
Edward: 10us
original: 15us
Edward: 15us
original: 15us
Edward: 10us
original: 15us
Edward: 10us
original: 15us
Edward: 10us
original: 15us
Edward: 10us
original: 15us
```

So it seems that the revised code is about 50% faster.

Comment: Your question inspired me to write [this one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158752/simple-linear-equation-solver) which implements all of these suggestions.

Comment: Still, you must also admit this is (by far) not the worst code ever. Working in companies, I at least often had to maintain code which was way worse.

Comment: It's not the worst, but it could be much better.  That's the point to Code Review.

Comment: @Edward - wow, thats a detailed review :) I'm still digesting parts of it (and looking at your posted code) - but I'm curious, what do you reckon to be complexity of your algorithm, since you are using a set for lookups?

Comment: It should be something a bit over logarithmic complexity, since that's the complexity of the `std::set` lookup. It's a bit over that because I don't bother to sort the variables by the number of dependencies; doing so as part of step 2 might speed things up slightly, but only if there were, on average, a large number of dependencies per variable.

Comment: @Edward Some inputs: 
1) The #endif is not a bug, it has a matching #ifdef at the beginning. Its not needed here for sure, its a practice i had picked up for an especially convolute project.

2) The `UL` was indeed defined as `unsigned long` in a `common.h` file that had other stuff related to the driver program - i should have imported that here, my bad!

3) I accept all other review comments - they indeed make it a better piece of code - *except the last one*. The Variable objects don't make sense outside of the equation of which its a part - think about multiple equation sets.

Comment: Continuing, if you don't use any associative structure such as queue/adjacency list, you'd end up querying for dependent variables from the set, each query taking logarithmic time (whereas the topological sort using BFS has a worst case complexity of O(n)). If I find some time, I'll post benchmark results using the automated equation generator I'd written (I'd have to modify your code to accept input from a file, and I'm rather pressed for time now :) ). But overall, your review was all I hoped for (despite the disagreement about the last point), thanks for taking the time to improve my code!

Comment: Better double check the `#endif` -- the `#if` is terminated just after the macro definition in the code you posted.

Comment: I've written and run a test harness to compare the speed of both versions and have added that to my answer.

Comment: As a sidenote, using `if (container.size() == 0)` would fail the interview for me on its own

Comment: @miscco: what would you propose as an alternative?

Comment: The correct way would be `if (!container.empty())`. This might be less harmfull in the case of solution_list, which is a vector (aka `!empy() -> begin() != end()` vs `size()==0 -> std::distance(begin(), end()) == 0`. However, if you do this on a std::set, you effectively walk the whole RB-tree instead of a single nullptr check

Comment: This is a `vector` and not a `set`, but it's a fair point.

Comment: Yes, but as always with `small` exceptions, they kind of expand easily ;) And `!empty()` is more expressive in any case

Answer (score 4):

For the code: just small things (some of which I already mentioned in the comments):

- The `#ifndef _EVALUATOR` part should be at the top of your header afaik. So you don't include all libraries again every time. p.s. `#pragma once`.
- `using namespace std;` you include a lot of libraries when you do this. Only add the functions you use: e.g. `using std::vector`.
- To use `Evaluator()`, you first have to create an object. I would have opted for a singleton instance and/or a static function.
- The 'helper functions' should from OO point of view at least have been part of `Evaluator`. But you could also have made a(n embedded) class e.g. `HelperFunctions` that contains the functions as static functions.
- I'm not sure about the `TRUE_OR_RETURN` macro. It probably works, but you're actually implementing you own exception handling. C++ has `try`, `throw` and `catch` for this purpose.
- **Comment your code**: if I look at for instance `AddNewVar` or `GetTopologicalVarOrder()` I see a lot that is happening, but I have no idea what! *There isn't a single line of comment in the code...* The person reviewing your code, or later a person maintaining it will have a *very* hard time trying to understand what the code is doing and why it is doing that.

But now lets look at the bigger picture: you seem to be under the assumption that you were declined because your code did not meet the standards. But is that really the case? You said you never heard from them again, so you don't really know. Did you ever ask them? It could be that something else happened: budgets were cut, they found someone internally, or you had some very good competition (you know: a guy that everyone wants, that has 20 years of experience and works for the salary of a 20-year old)

In my culture (the Netherlands) it is quite common to contact the company to ask what the status of your application is. Usually we call a week after we assumed our application letter was received. Etc. Then, if you are turned down it is quite normal if you ask them for the reasons. I don't see why you should just try contacting them about this. If they don't reply, it might not even be the kind of company you want to work for.

Now you're just making assumptions that your code is bad and worrying about that. But it looks quite reasonable to me.

By the way: What kind (level) of function were you applying for? Senior software architect? Or just a starting position? It could be that you aimed too high for a first job?

Comment: Thanks for the review! In response to your first comment, I've contacted the company multiple times after a week of the submission (email, even left a voicemail with the recruiter) - no responses as of this moment.

Comment: You're welcome. But apparently my review is not worthy of any votes ;p

Comment: Ahh - I thought the OP should vote after a couple of days, so as to not discourage other posters :). Fixed that btw :P

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius, I believe you could move the non review part to the bottom, so people could read the review part and skip the non review part if they want to. The review part is good.

Comment: @Incomputable ... So the other part isn't good?

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius, it is off-topic :) from site's perspective it is bad, but it would be good in general forum.