# Implementing and benchmarking Radix Sort on unsigned integers

Tags: c++, sorting, c++17, benchmarking

### Introduction

I implemented a restricted version of the sorting algorithm, the one that works only with unsigned integers. I wanted to try using `std::stable_partition` with bitmask, as I chose base 2. The reason partition works here is because there are only two "bins", thus it is somewhat like partitioning. I mandated customizing the maximum power of two that is encountered in the sequence.

---

### Code

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

namespace shino
{
    template <typename BidirIterator>
    void radix_sort(BidirIterator first, BidirIterator last, unsigned upper_power_bound)
    {
        using category = typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIterator>::iterator_category;
        using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIterator>::value_type;
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, category>,
                "At least bidirectional iterators are required");
        static_assert(std::is_integral_v<value_type> and std::is_unsigned_v<value_type>,
                      "Only unsigned integers are supported for radix sort");
        value_type mask = 1;
        for (auto power = 0u; power <= upper_power_bound; ++power)
        {
            auto predicate = [mask](const auto& value)
            {
                return !(value & mask);
            };
            std::stable_partition(first, last, predicate);
            mask <<= 1;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Weird results

The algorithm has a lottle of wiggle regarding the constant factor, though it is linear. The picture below is for highest power of 16, x-axis is element count, and y-axis is nanoseconds (sorry I'm not on good terms with gnuplot). So it takes ~1.6 *milliseconds* to sort 30'000 elements, which is I think quite a lot for linear sorting algorithm.

[image: Performance of radix sort]

I believe those spikes are context switches, but I couldn't verify that. It seems like there is no way to reliably track them and correspond to the spike.

---

### Full code

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

std::vector<unsigned> generate_vector(std::size_t size, unsigned power_limit)
{
    auto generator = [power_limit]
    {
        static std::mt19937 twister{};
        static std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned > dist{0u, (1u << power_limit)};
        return dist(twister);
    };

    std::vector<unsigned> v(size);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), generator);

    return v;
}

#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

namespace shino
{
    template <typename BidirIterator>
    void radix_sort(BidirIterator first, BidirIterator last, unsigned upper_power_bound)
    {
        using category = typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIterator>::iterator_category;
        using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIterator>::value_type;
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, category>,
                "At least bidirectional iterators are required");
        static_assert(std::is_integral_v<value_type> and std::is_unsigned_v<value_type>,
                      "Only unsigned integers are supported for radix sort");
        value_type mask = 1;
        for (auto power = 0u; power <= upper_power_bound; ++power)
        {
            auto predicate = [mask](const auto& value)
            {
                return !(value & mask);
            };
            std::stable_partition(first, last, predicate);
            mask <<= 1;
        }
    }
}

#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

namespace shino
{
    template <typename Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
    class stopwatch
    {
        const typename Clock::time_point start_point;
    public:
        stopwatch() :
                start_point(Clock::now())
        {}

        template <typename Rep = typename Clock::duration::rep, typename Units = typename Clock::duration>
        Rep elapsed_time() const
        {
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            auto counted_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<Units>(Clock::now() - start_point).count();
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_relaxed);
            return static_cast<Rep>(counted_time);
        }
    };

    using precise_stopwatch = stopwatch<>;
    using system_stopwatch = stopwatch<std::chrono::system_clock>;
    using monotonic_stopwatch = stopwatch<std::chrono::steady_clock>;
}

#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream measurings("measurings.csv");
    if (!measurings)
        throw std::runtime_error("measurings file opening failed");

    for (unsigned power = 4; power <= 16; ++power)
    {
        for (auto size = 0ull; size <= 20'000; ++size)
        {
            std::cout << "radix sorting vector of size " << size << '\n';
            auto input = generate_vector(size, power);
            shino::precise_stopwatch stopwatch;
            shino::radix_sort(input.begin(), input.end(), power);
            auto elapsed_time = stopwatch.elapsed_time();
            measurings << power << ',' << size << ',' << elapsed_time << '\n';
            if (not std::is_sorted(input.begin(), input.end()))
                throw std::logic_error("radix sort doesn't work correctly on size " + std::to_string(size));
        }
    }
}
```

The code records performance and checks if sort actually worked correctly. So if you make any changes, just run the code to test it. `stopwatch` code is taken from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196253/93301). In fact, I believe it deserves a review on its own.

I couldn't get gnuplot to plot 3d graphs, sorry no pics for the changes related to maximum power.

---

### Concerns

- Is algorithm implemented well?

Are there points to improve performance? Make a better use of standard library?

- Will the inner lambda cause code bloat?

Lambdas are anonymous classes, so will be instantiated for every version of radix sort itself. I'm unsure if using lambda was a wise choice.

- Anything else that comes to mind

Comment: One issue is when you calculate the elapsed time.  This should be done right after the sorting is done, _before_ you start doing any output.  That output will have variable amounts of additional time, depending on the internals of `ofstream` and in particular when it needs to stop and flush the data buffer to disk.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, thanks, fixed. I guess I shouldn't write algorithms after 20 hours of no sleep...

Comment: Does the stopwatch class take efforts to prevent code movement during optimization and re-ordering during execution?  It could be inaccurate on the scale of a few hundred instructions.

Comment: @JDługosz, I believe it does. I’m not sure though.

Comment: Could I get a copy of your cvs file please? :)

Comment: @Rakete1111, I posted it at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/CrsFeWBr). Just hit ctrl+a and ctrl+v to paste. Sorry, it seems like there is government restrictions on google lately ...

Comment: @Incomputable Don't be, it's okay :) Thanks though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll focus *just* on the algorithm (not the timing code), and the questions.

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, category>,
    "At least bidirectional iterators are required");
static_assert(std::is_integral_v<value_type> and std::is_unsigned_v<value_type>,
    "Only unsigned integers are supported for radix sort");
```

It seems a bit superfluous to say "`static_assert(is_foo, "must be foo")`". The assertion predicates are clear enough on their own to not require additional explanation. Also, I wouldn't recommend combining requirements. It makes it harder to diagnose exactly which assertion failed:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, category>);
static_assert(std::is_integral_v<value_type>);
static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<value_type>);
```

Down to the lambda:

```
auto predicate = [mask](const auto& value)
{
    return !(value & mask);
};
```

Unless you're planning to support non-fundamental integer types, taking the argument by `const&` is probably an unnecessary pessimization. Even if it's not a built-in type, if the binary `&` operator and conversion to `bool` are implemented sanely, the lambda's frame can be basically optimized away. It's nice to be able to do everything in-line:

```
std::stable_partition(first, last, [mask](auto v) { return !(v & mask); });
```

As for the questions:

**Is it implemented well?** I'd say so. I can't think of many improvements/extensions I'd make. Maybe a check to make sure `upper_power_bound` is less than the number of bits in `value_type` so you're not just spinning your wheels... but that could be tricky to pull off generally if you're supporting non-builtin integer types (maybe check to see if `mask` is zero, assuming the `1` bit drops off the end into the ether if you shift it too far?). Maybe a range version, but that's a pretty trivial addition once the iterator version's working.

**Will the inner lambda cause code bloat?** No. On any compiler worth mentioning and on any optimization level worth caring about, it will be inlined - likely to a single instruction, maybe two (assuming a built-in unsigned type). Modern compilers are *terrifyingly* good at optimizing lambdas (or anything where all the code is right there in front of them, really).

Even if it weren't inlined to effectively nothing, the lambda would be *dwarfed* by `std::stable_partition()`'s code. Like by two or three orders of magnitude, easy. It's totally not something to worry about.