# Measuring execution time of a function

Tags: c++, benchmarking

I was trying to emulate python's `timeit` in C++. My main aim for this is to measure the performance of small functions of C++ code that I write and print some basic stats like avg., min, max.

#### Code:

`ctimeit.h`:

```
#ifndef CTIMEIT_H
#define CTIMEIT_H

#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

namespace ctimeit {
using GetTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
std::string format_time(int64_t);

template <size_t N = 1000, typename Callable, typename... Args>
void timeit(Callable func, Args&&... Funcargs) {
  /*
   * Measure the average execution time of `func` which takes `Funcargs`
   * after `N` executions.
   */

  double total_time{0};
  int64_t min_exec_time{std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()}, max_exec_time{0};

  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    auto start = GetTime::now();
    func(std::forward<Args>(Funcargs)...);
    auto end = GetTime::now();

    auto run_time =
        duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
    min_exec_time = std::min(min_exec_time, run_time);
    max_exec_time = std::max(max_exec_time, run_time);
    total_time += run_time;
  }

  std::cout << "Average time taken : " << format_time(total_time / N) << " ("
            << N << " runs)\n"
            << "Max time taken     : " << format_time(max_exec_time) << "\n"
            << "Min time taken     : " << format_time(min_exec_time) << "\n";
}

std::string format_time(int64_t run_time) {
  /*
   * For setting the scale of execution time.
   */

  std::string formats[]{"ns", "µs", "ms", "s"};
  float scaling[]{1, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9};
  int pow = std::floor(std::log10(run_time));
  int idx = std::max(0, pow / 3);
  return std::to_string(run_time / scaling[idx]) + formats[idx];
}

}  // namespace ctimeit

#endif  // CTIMEIT_H
```

---

**Output:**

```
std::cout<<"-------SomeFunc---------\n";
timeit(SomeFunc, v); //default N i.e 1000
std::cout<<"-------anotherFunc with N arg---------\n";
timeit<100>(anotherFunc, 10, 20, 40.f);


-------SomeFunc---------
Average time taken : 904.073975µs (1000 runs)
Max time taken     : 4.574131ms
Min time taken     : 834.716003µs
-------anotherFunc with N arg---------
Average time taken : 45.000000ns (100 runs)
Max time taken     : 137.000000ns
Min time taken     : 39.000000ns
```

Any suggestions to improve my code or if there's anything wrong I'm doing in measuring the execution time?

Comment: The example output (with exact nanoseconds) suggests that you're trying to show more precision than your platform provides.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, I think I'm passing `total_time/N` which is `double` to `format_time` which takes `int64_t`, losing all the precision. And `scaling` array is in `float` too that's why the output has less precision. Thank you I would have completely missed these details if not for your comment.

Comment: Related:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58055/stopwatch-template

Comment: If you actually want to time your code well, use an external profiler. They do a much better job.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend reading up on [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) and suggest you modify how you output your numbers during the next revision of your program.

Comment: @Mast Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is unfortunately using a very naive method to measure the execution time of a function. I'll discuss a few of the issues and how to solve them below.

## Avoid `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`

While the name sounds like it's what you want, there is unfortunately no guarantee whether this clock follows the wall clock or the monotonic clock. This means that if you are unfortunate enough that your NTP daemon is making an adjustment to the wall clock time while your benchmark is running, the results will be incorrect. [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) is the best clock from the C++ standard to use to avoid surprises.

Even then, this might not be the best clock to measure the time your *process* spends executing functions. Consider that your operating system might have to handle interrupts or schedule other tasks on the same CPU core your benchmark is running on. Most operating systems have some clocks that will only count while your process is running. These are not standardized, but on POSIX systems you could consider using [`clock_gettime()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID.

## Measuring time costs time

Calling `GetTime::now()` itself costs time; it might involve having to make system calls depending on the operating system. If you are going to take the time twice for each time you call `func()`, and if `func()` is a relatively fast function, you might start measuring the performance of `GetTime::now()` instead of the performance of `func()`. I did some tests where I ran your original code and a modified version that moves the calls to `GetTime::now()` out of the loop. The result for a function that does a few calculations was:

- Your code: 48 ns
- Modified code: 28 ns

This is a difference of 20 ns, which corresponds exactly with some measurements of how long `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)` takes on my machine.

Another way to avoid the issue is to keep measuring time like you do now, but run the loop twice: once while calling `func()`, another time while calling a function that does nothing. Subtract the two to get the time actually spent inside `func()`, without including the overhead of time measurent and function call overhead.

## Be aware of clock granularity

Clocks are not infinitely precise. On Linux on x86 processors, the `steady_clock` and `high_resolution_clock`s typically have a resolution of 1 ns. If you are measuring a function that takes just a few nanoseconds, this means you will have roundoff errors each time you measure the time. Those roundoff errors accumulate in your loop. This is another reason to just take the time before and after the loop to get a good average.

Also consider that there are systems where the clocks have a lower resolution. For example, if you are on a platform where the system clock's resolution is only one microsecond, but the function you are trying to measure only takes 500 nanoseconds, you really need to run the function multiple times between time measurements.

## Avoid casting durations too early

This is already mentioned by Toby Speight, just use `GetTime::duration` as the type for `run_time`, `total_time`, `min_exec_time` and `max_exec_time`. This type has the right precision for durations measured using the `GetTime` clock. (Maybe also just rename this to `clock`, otherwise it sounds like a function.)

Only convert to a floating point number right before printing the measured durations, so basically have `format_time()` take a duration as a parameter.
The exception is the average time; you want to convert the total time to a floating point number before dividing by `N`.

## Do a warm-up before taking actual measurements

Calling a function for the first time might take longer than calling the same function a subsequent time, because the first time it might not have been loaded into the CPU's caches, the CPU's branch predictor might not know how to predict it, any memory allocations might be expensive in the beginning, any file I/O might not hit the page cache yet, and so on. You need a warm-up run to ensure all these things have "warmed up". This will take more than just calling the function once. I suggest you run the whole loop twice, and only use the statistics from the second time you run the loop. You might even consider running the loop many times, and only stopping when the results have stabilized.

## Automatically scale the number of loop iterations

Consider running a loop with just a small number of iterations first to get a rough estimate of how long the function takes. Then decide for how long you want to run the benchmark, something between 1 and 10 seconds is a reasonable default. Then you can automatically choose the number of iterations based on the desired runtime of the benchmark divided by the estimated time the function takes.

Comment: More than I expected. Thank you for such a detailed review and on where I can improve. I was wondering why `max time taken` is significantly higher than `avg.`, good to know why. Great review I'll try to incorporate all the mention points. Thank you.

Comment: On granularity: _"Also consider that there are systems where the clocks have a lower resolution [...] you really need to run the function multiple times between time measurements."_ Actually not really; imagine a task that takes 1 hour and you try to measure its duration using a device with a resolution of 1 day. If sampled repeatedly and randomly, in the majority of measurements the task will appear to start and end on the same day with duration = 0. However 1 in 24 times, it will run through midnight, appearing to take 24 hours. Averaging the measurements, the 1 hour duration is still found.

Comment: @Greedo That only works if you do exactly a multiple of 24 measurements in that scenario. But it's much more likely you don't do the right amount of measurements for the measured average to be the actual average. To minimize the error in the measurement, just measure the duration of the whole loop instead of summing the durations of each individual iteration.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Imagine you sample 1000 times, 41 take 24 hours, 959 take 0 then the average is 0.98 hours which is not exactly 1 but that's fine - you can quantify the uncertainty of this estimate using the student-t distribution. The problem with doing them back to back is the central limit theorem - if you want to know the distribution of values, not just the average (so max/min like OP uses, or maybe StDev or shape of distribution) then squashing everything together you lose that info and runtimes appear more gaussian than they really were. This will make max/min closer to the mean than reality

Comment: ... so yeah, if your measurement resolution gives some uncertainty to a single measurement, then by taking `n` in a loop and measuring only once, you can divide that uncertainty by `sqrt(n)`, like measuring many sheets of paper in a stack with a ruler rather than one by one. However you lose information about variation in thickness of the paper, as this gets averaged out. You can estimate it by measuring several stacks and working out the StDev, then scaling that up by `sqrt(n)`, however this assumes the paper thickness is gaussian and there's no way to validate this because that info is lost.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I think, IIUC :). I've been working with execution timing and uncertainties a lot recently. Too much to discuss in the comments though

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing `int64_t` is intended to be `std::int64_t`?  Don't assume that all compilers declare these types in the global namespace as well as `std`.  If `std::int64_t` is present, it's declared in `<cstdint>`, so be sure to include that.  Your code could be more portable if you used e.g. `std::uint_fast64_t` - or in this case, `std::chrono::nanoseconds::rep`.

`std::size_t` is consistently misspelt, too.

---

Accumulating values into a `double` is likely to lose precision.  I'd be inclined to keep the total as a duration, rather than converting to numeric type.

---

> ```
>   int idx = std::max(0, pow / 3);
>   return std::to_string(run_time / scaling[idx]) + formats[idx];
> ```

Although we've taken care here not to run off the beginning of the array, we haven't taken the same care with the end (kiloseconds).  We probably want

```
const std::array formats = {"ns", "µs", "ms", "s"};
auto idx = std::clamp(pow / 3, 0, static_cast<int>(formats.size() - 1));
```

Also, be careful using names such as `pow` which are also in the C standard library.  That can hamper quick comprehension by your code's readers.

This utility function `format_time()` probably deserves its own unit tests, to ensure that extremes are handled well.

Comment: I really wouldn't categorize the issue of the type names not necessarily being in the global namespace in a conforming implementation as a _spelling_ error.  It's a mistake in not knowing that it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you @Toby. I was under the false impression that `int64_t` are available in the global scope. Great review! `std::array formats = {"ns"...}` what would be the type of array is it `array<std:string>` or `array<const char *>`?

Comment: @Ch3steR several implementations make it available in the root namespace. This is allowed, but it is not guaranteed and thus must not be relied upon.

Comment: That would be an array of `const char*` (since `auto s = "ns"` deduces to `const char*`).  If you wanted `std::string`, there's a suffix operator in `std::literals`.

Comment: The types are or are not required to be in the global namespace depending on which header was used to introduce them.  Looking at the headers included by OP's code, I don't think those names are guaranteed to be available *anywhere*.  `#include <inttypes.h>` would guarantee they exist in the global namespace, where the code expects to find them.

Comment: @ben that's true, though in that case, I would advise using the C++ header `<cinttypes>`, for the usual reasons.  And I note the code includes C++ header `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 4):

There's a glaring bug in how you forward arguments

```
template <size_t N = 1000, typename Callable, typename... Args>
void timeit(Callable func, Args&&... Funcargs) {
    // ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        // ...
        func(std::forward<Args>(Funcargs)...);
    // ...
}
```

Consider this

```
timeit([](std::string s){ s += s; }, std::string("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"));
```

You move the string in the first iteration, and henceforth the string is in a valid but unspecified state, usually just empty. Either way, that's not what you want. A quick fix is

```
template <typename... Args, typename Callable, typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
void forward_apply(Callable func, Tuple& args, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(get<Is>(args))...);
}

template <size_t N = 1000, typename Callable, typename... Args>
void timeit(Callable func, Args&&... Funcargs) {
    // ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        auto args = std::tuple(Funcargs...);
        // ...
        forward_apply<Args&&...>(func, args, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    // ...
}
```

where you make a copy of the arguments without timing them, and then forward them as specified by the argument types.

At this point, `timeit` has rather convoluted semantics. What if the arguments aren't copyable? Should `Callable` be copied and forwarded similarly to the arguments? A solution provided by the standard library is to use `std::reference_wrapper` to opt *out* of copying. However, the complexity for both users and implementer gets even greater.

You could limit the scope of what `timeit` is supposed to do

```
template <size_t N = 1000, typename Callable>
void timeit(Callable&& func) {
    // ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        // ...
        func();
    // ...
}
```

The semantics is simple: `timeit` repeatedly calls `operator()` on the `func` object passed in, and it's up to the user to decide what to do with arguments. It is however impossible to omit argument copying time in such a design.

Comment: Great point about `Callable` being not copyable. Should I make `Callable` a `forwarding reference` too? would that be good?

Comment: Thank you for the review again. Since I started learning C++ recently it took some time to understand everything. It made me think maybe redesigning my whole approach might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Maybe a solution to keep this simple is to just not pass `Funcargs` to `timeit()`. Instead, let the caller pass a lambda which has captured the arguments.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I considered that, but then it means you always benchmark whatever you do with the arguments. If the user doesn't want to include the copying time, they can't.

Comment: @Ch3steR Whether to forward `Callable` is a design choice. You could require that `Callable::operator()` not modify its state, which is what your current version means. You could also do what I did with the arguments (copy and forward). Or you could use `std::reference_wrapper` to opt out of copying. If it were me though, I'd choose the first.

Comment: @G.Sliepen On second thought, that sounds fine. This function isn't ever going to be a full featured benchmarking suite anyways.